# Visual studio caching information about project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to work on a project in Visual Studio 2008 Professional. Earlier, the project was saved on a network location. Its an opensource project, I browsed the original code for some time, compiled and ran it. Then I deleted it from its original location, and then redownloaded it into a new location on my desktop. Then I opened Visual Studio and removed the reference to the project from the recently used Projects. However, when I open the project again, I see that it references some old project paths, from the network share. e.g. Z:\mb\mb, when the new project is actually stored in C:\users\me\MightBox. 
Example error: Access to the path Z:\mb\mb\app\MightyBoxApp\bin\Debug is denied 
EDIT: Forgot to mention, I have used a grep -nri "z:\\" * and there are not matches in the directory, hence it is almost certain that VS is somehow caching the information.

I would be really grateful if somebody could help me as I'm spending a lot of time on it. Thanks.

EDIT: The problem was that my application had cached its earlier location and it was NO FAULT OF VISUAL STUDIO. I repeat, there is no caching of any sorts happening here in Visual Studio. Actually, the application was caching the location of its last run and hence the problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try opening up the following folder and see if it has the information you want to delete

> %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio

Certain project types, web IIRC, store some information in that location for certain projects.  If that doesn't have the data you may also want to try HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0

Comment: Oh. The problem was that my application had cached its earlier location and it was NO FAULT OF VISUAL STUDIO. I repeat, there is no caching of any sorts happening here in Visual Studio. Is there any way I can delete this question so that people don't get misled. Thanks for the answer. Only because of this did I manage to figure out that the app cached its earlier location.

Comment: @user247077 I think the best solution is to just update your question with this comment.